# java - jooq - how to bind array as param in jooq - PostgreSQL

Tags: java, arrays, postgresql, list, jooq

how to bind an array as param in the query of jooq?

This is where i'm adding a named parameter with name 'someIds'

```
    Query query = selectJoinStep.where(field("some.id").in(param("someIds")));
```

I tried the line below to bind the an array to the param

```
    query.bind("someIds", someIds);
```

but in the generated sql i'm getting the reference of the object and not the actual values as shown below

> some.id in ('[Ljava.lang.Object;@1fee4fe3')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Why doesn't your approach work?

It is a common misconception that the SQL `IN (?)` predicate can somehow support array bind variables. This isn't possible in any SQL dialect I'm aware of, and neither can you do it this way with jOOQ. By "this way", I mean specifying a single bind variable marker (`param`) and bind several IDs to it.

The reason why you're getting that particular error message is that jOOQ tries to bind an actual array bind variable to the single parameter. As you probably know, PostgreSQL supports arrays, and if you had bound an `Integer[]`, then jOOQ would have passed that on to the PostgreSQL JDBC driver. In fact, maybe that's what you really want to do here by using the PostgreSQL specific `= ANY(?)` predicate

```java
field("some.id").eq(any(someIds))
```

#### Dynamic `IN` lists

In order to have dynamic `IN`-lists, you have to pass a dynamic list of params, e.g.

```java
field("some.id").in(IntStream.range(0, someIds.length)
                             .mapToObj(i -> param("someId" + i))
                             .collect(Collectors.toList()))
```

And then, you will have to bind your ids individually using

```java
for (int i = 0; i < someIds.length; i++)
    query.bind("someId" + i, someIds[i]);
```

Or, of course, you bind them directly to the in-predicate:

```java
field("some.id").in(IntStream.range(0, someIds.length)
                             .mapToObj(i -> param("someId" + i, i))
                             .collect(Collectors.toList()))
```

Comment: thanks for the response, in the end I used field("some.id").eq(any(someIds))