# jooq - generate array comparison using contains

Tags: java, jooq

I'm trying to check if a field is in an array for a select query. This is the query I want to make:

```sql
select item_id, name, desc from item_table where contains(array[24805247, 2156654], item_id);
```

This is for AWS Athena / Presto

The [first example in the jOOQ docs for plain SQL template](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.19/manual-single-page/#plain-sql) shows converting objects to arrays, but I can't seem to make that work.

In the example, `condition("{0} && {1}", array1, array2);` becomes `ARRAY[1,4,3] && ARRAY[2,1]`. When I try this with one array it only passes the first item in the array rather than converting to an array.

My array is all integers: `Integer[] items`.

This is the code I tried:

```java
var create = DSL.using(SQLDialect.DEFAULT);
var query = create.select(item_id, name, desc)
                .from(table("item_table"))
                .where("contains({0}, item_id)", items)
                .getSQL(ParamType.INLINED);
```

I saw this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49199733/java-jooq-how-to-bind-array-as-param-in-jooq-postgresql) but when I change the where to `.where(items.eq(any(item_id)))`, the query is composed of a bunch of `item_id = 24805247 or item_id = 2156654`.

I want the query to use an array like in the example because eventually I will be querying about 30-50 item IDs (this is a weekly background task so speed isn't a huge issue).

Answer (score 0):

You're using a template placeholder `{0}`, when you should be using a bind parameter marker `?` (assuming `items is indeed a Java array):

```java
.where("contains(?, item_id)", items)
```

Alternatively, if you prefer using template placeholders, you must pass a `QueryPart`, e.g. an [explicit bind variable](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/):

```java
.where("contains({0}, item_id)", val(items))
```

Comment: I've tried it both ways and it still doesn't generate an array

Comment: @Goigle: Well, your dialect isn't supported in jOOQ 3.18, and the `SQLDialect.DEFAULT`'s behaviour isn't really defined for production usage (see Javadoc), so I don't know what else I could offer here...